# wp_insert_term doesn't work with custom post type's taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

Here is the problem I am having:

1. I have a custom post type called "weddingguests"
2. This custom post type "weddingguests" has a custom taxonomy, "friendsof", hierarchic
3. I want to programmatically insert into this custom taxonomy "friendsof" 2 terms: "Friends of the Bride" and "Friends of the Groom"

Here is the function and the action I am using to insert one term:

```
// programatically add 2 terms to the taxonomy "FRIENDS OF"
function example_insert_category() {
    wp_insert_term(
        'Example Category',
        'friendsof'
    );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'example_insert_category' );
```

The problem: wp_insert_term doesn't appear to be working with my custom taxonomy

What I have tried:

1. I have tried switching the taxonomy from hierarchic to non-hierarchic - that didn't work
2. I have tried using wp_insert_term (the same code) to add terms to the post "category" - that is working
3. I have tried assigning the custom taxonomy "friendsof" to the posts and then add my term ( I thought there is a problem with the way I am building my custom post types) - that didn't work

Comment: do you have debugging enabled and have you tried inspecting the data that WordPress returns from `wp_insert_term`?

Comment: To insert a term in a taxonomy you must be sure that taxonomy is registered *before* the code that insert term runs. If you use `'after_setup_theme'` to register the taxonomy, you should use a later hook to insert the terms. `wp_loaded` hook is best choice for such code. However, as @s_ha_dum suggests, you should put that code inside a conditional: `if ( ! term_exists( 'example-category', 'friendsof' ) )` and trigger that code (i.e. put the `add_action` ) on theme switch or on plugin activation.

Comment: @gmazzap Thanks for that answer man, saved me a bunch of time.

Answer (score 4):

try **init** instead of **after_setup_theme**

```
function example_insert_category() {
    wp_insert_term(
        'Example Category',
        'friendsof'
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'example_insert_category' );
```

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know *why* and don't have time to investigate right now, the hook you've chosen is too early. Your code works if you use, for example, `init` instead of `after_setup_theme`.

In addition, as written, your code runs on every page load which is a bit profligate. There should be a way execute this only on plugin activation or perhaps on a change of theme-- something that reduces the frequency this executes. Perhaps best case is a button in the theme/plugin to "Populate Defaults". Once this runs once it is not needed anymore as the data is in the database.